# LibGDX: Creating a GestureListener in a separate class

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I currently have a class which handles all the gestures I want and it looks like this:

```
public class InputHandler  implements GestureDetector.GestureListener{

  private Player myPlayer;

  public InputHandler(Player player){
    myPlayer = player;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean touchDown(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean tap(float x, float y, int count, int button) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean longPress(float x, float y) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean fling(float velocityX, float velocityY, int button) {
    if(velocityY > 0){
      myPlayer.onSwipeUp();
    }
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean pan(float x, float y, float deltaX, float deltaY) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean panStop(float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean zoom(float initialDistance, float distance) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean pinch(Vector2 initialPointer1, Vector2 initialPointer2, Vector2 pointer1, Vector2 pointer2) {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public void pinchStop() {

  }
}
```

As you can see, the only method I'm using is the "fling" method but I would like to create the Gesture listener in my 'MainScreen' class as it contains a reference to 'myPlayer' which I want to pass into this class but I'm not sure how to create the listener. So far I have this in my constructor:

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

  private GameWorld world;
  private GameRenderer renderer;
  GestureDetector gd;


  public GameScreen(){
    float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float gameWidth = 816;
    float gameHeight = screenHeight/(screenWidth/gameWidth);

    int midpointY = (int)(gameHeight/2);

    world = new GameWorld(midpointY);
    renderer = new GameRenderer(world);

    gd = new GestureDetector(new myGestureListener(world.getPlayer())); //Error here, 'myGestureListener' cannot be resolved
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gd);



  }
```

I understand that 'myGestureListener' has never been created and thus cannot be resolved but I'm confused as to how I can fix this error while also ensuring that the reference is passed correctly. If I need to initialize a GestureListener, how would I do that?

I apologize in advance if this question makes no sense or there isn't a solution, I'm still new to coding using the libGDX framework.

Comment: you didn't make a class called `myGestureListener`.

Comment: Apart from the answer to your question which has been given below, here's a tip: Try to decouple the listener from your Player (following the SOLID principles) If you just need to catch fling() events, create a simple Interface with a fling() method, have GameScreen implement this interface and pass the absctracted GameScreen to InputHandler(FlingListener listener)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a class called `myGestureListener`?

From your question it seems you called it `InputHandler`, so maybe you used the wrong name.

Comment: Oh my, I don't know how I didn't catch that. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

InputHandler is your GestureListener implemented class so make object of that class and pass as argument in GestureDetector constructor.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {

  private GameWorld world;
  private GameRenderer renderer;
  private GestureDetector gd;

  public GameScreen(){
    float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float gameWidth = 816;
    float gameHeight = screenHeight/(screenWidth/gameWidth);

    int midpointY = (int)(gameHeight/2);

    world = new GameWorld(midpointY);
    renderer = new GameRenderer(world);

    gd = new GestureDetector(new InputHandler(world.getPlayer())); 
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(gd);
  }
```